# How to fix ios notch issues using ionic 5 and capacitor 3?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, capacitor

To fix the app being under the notch, I tried several things, but to no avail

- adding the following to `index.html`

```
<meta name="viewport"
  content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

- adding the following CSS

```
@supports (padding: max(16px)) {
  body {
    padding: env(safe-area-inset-top) env(safe-area-inset-right)
                env(safe-area-inset-bottom) env(safe-area-inset-left);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ionic iPhone X safe areas not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48044636/ionic-iphone-x-safe-areas-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 7):

Try adding the following in your global.scss file:

```
body {
    margin-top: constant(safe-area-inset-top);
    margin-top: env(safe-area-inset-top);
    margin-bottom: calc(4px + env(safe-area-inset-top));
}
```

Padding doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in ionic 6.7 and try below code and it worked

**index.html**

`<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`

**global.scss**

```
// ios bottom iphone x fixed
body {
  margin-top: constant(safe-area-inset-top);
  margin-top: env(safe-area-inset-top);
}

ion-tab-bar {
  margin-bottom: calc(7px + env(safe-area-inset-top));
}
```

**variables.scss**

```
:root{
--ion-safe-area-bottom: 14px;
}

.ios{
    --ion-safe-area-top : -1 !important;
  --ion-safe-area-bottom: 14px;
}
```